# change owner of sub-folder in mounted partition

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, chown

I know there are several similar question. I'm also using linux for quite a while but there is possibly something now that I can't see and I reached a dead end.

I have a partition mounted with /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=2660328660325CAD /mnt/doc        ntfs      suid,dev,exec,auto,nouser,umask=0022 0  0
```

and as expected this is the mounted partition:

```
# ll -ld /mnt/doc/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 dic 27  2021 /mnt/doc/
```

This partition will hold files and folder belonging to different users

I tried:

```
# chown -R USER:USER-GROUP /mnt/doc/USER_FOLDER/
```

but the USER-FOLDER is still own by root. After sending the command in the terminal there is no error given.

I've double checked the fstab options without results

I think I'm definetively missing some information and any hints will be really welcome cuz so far my only alternative is to mount the partition with umask=0000 which is the least I want

Thanks a lot

Comment: Take a look at the `mount.ntfs` man page. You will likely need the `allow_other` mount option, as well as possible user mappings. Side note: are you sure you want to allow setuid and setgid on the shared file system?